# Converting tweets text to a Json format

Tags: android, json, twitter, okhttp

I am trying to get my tweets from the web using `Okhttp3` , Is there a way to get my tweets as `Json` format to show them in a listview?

Comment: Can you please share some link for how you getting your tweets using Okhttp3?

Comment: why is that important ?